# Which view controllers that are not loaded from your main storyboard at launch time

Tags: ios

I am studying the iOS and from the article of Apple: iOS App Programming Guide, section "State Preservation and Restoration" I see this:

> For each view controller you choose to preserve, you also need to decide on how you want to restore it later. UIKit offers two ways to recreate objects. You can let your app delegate recreate it or you can assign a restoration class to the view controller and let that class recreate it. A restoration class implements the UIViewControllerRestoration protocol and is responsible for finding or creating a designated object at restore time. Here are some tips for when to use each one:
>
> **If the view controller is always loaded from your app’s main storyboard file at launch time**, do not assign a restoration class. Instead, let your app delegate find the object or take advantage of UIKit’s support for implicitly finding restored objects.
> **For view controllers that are not loaded from your main storyboard file at launch time**, assign a restoration class. The simplest option is to make each view controller its own restoration class.

Could someone give me an example of **Which view controllers that are not loaded from my main storyboard at launch time**
because I understand that view controllers is used to control the display of views for UI, so they all must be attached to a storyboard when we design the scenes of our app, therefore when Storyboard is load at launch time, all view controllers in our app is loaded also.

Comment: I assume you are fairly new to iOS and this is not a feature you need to worry about! This feature is used to bring the user right back where he was when the app was quit in the background (which usually happens when it wasn't opened in quite a while or your users use resource heavy apps and your application will be terminated in the background.

Comment: what do you mean by load ? (enter in viewDidLoad: ?)

Comment: I mean the term "load" here is when the view controller is pushed/presented. And "view controller is always loaded from your app’s main storyboard file at launch time" means when it was push/presented during the Launching phase, from Main() -> UIApplicationMain() -> Load main UI file -> application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: -> application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Answer (score 0):

> **view controllers that are not loaded from your main storyboard file at launch time**

This refers to any view controller that is pushed/presented after launch. For instance, if you had a list controller which pushed a detail controller via `UINavigationController`, the list controller and navigation controller are loaded at launch time, but the detail controller is not.

Comment: So, it seems that every view controllers relating to the first screen appears to user when he see the app, will be the view controllers loaded from the storyboard at launch time, is this your answer ?
And every other view controllers relating to other screens when users navigate during using app will be loaded later, and for this kind of view controller we need to make their Restoration Class to manage state preservation, is that right?

Comment: Kind regards to help me enter the iOS world, Austin :)